# Гармоническая строка

Tags: javascript

Назовем строку гармоничным,если в строке количество символов **b** не превышает количество символов **a**,количество **c** не превышает **b** и так далее.

Пример гармонической строки **"aaaabbbcc"**

Написать **solution** функцию,которая проверяет строка гармоническая или нет.

> Проверял найти сумму строки с помощью charCodeAt и проверять она простая или составная,но не всегда получается правильным

```
function solution(x){
var s = 0
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    s += x[i].charCodeAt(0)
}
return s%2!=0
}
console.log(solution("bbbaacdafe")) //true
console.log(solution("aaaabbbc")) //true
console.log(solution("aabbb")) //false
console.log(solution("aaabbb")) //true
console.log(solution("aabbbcccccc")) //false
console.log(solution("bbc")) //false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
function solution(str) {
  str = str.split('').sort().join('');
  //создаем объект, в который записываем коды символов и количество их повторений
  const done = {};
  for (const char of str) {
    const charCode = char.charCodeAt(0);
    charCode in done ? done[charCode] += 1: done[charCode] = 1
  };
  let prevCount = Infinity;
  let nextCharCode = 'a'.charCodeAt(0);
  for (let charCode in done) {
    // Если количество повторений предыдущего символа больше за количество повторений следующего
    // Или код следующего символа больше за код предыдущего не на 1
    if(done[charCode] > prevCount || charCode != nextCharCode++) {
      return false
    } else {
      prevCount = done[charCode];
      prevCharCode = charCode;
    }
  }
  return true;
};

console.log(solution("bbbaacdafe")) //true
console.log(solution("aaaabbbc")) //true
console.log(solution("aabbb")) //false
console.log(solution("aaabbb")) //true
console.log(solution("aabbbcccccc")) //false
console.log(solution("bbc")) // false
```

Comment: потому что там нету буквы a

Comment: @ROBBSTARK, исправил. Теперь считает правильно относительно задания

Comment: спасибо огромное Вам

Answer (score 0):

```js
function solution(string) {
  const codeCount = new Map()
  string.split('').forEach((s) => {
    let code = s.charCodeAt(0)
    let c = codeCount.get(code)
    codeCount.set(code, c ? ++c : 1)
  })
  const array = [...codeCount.entries()].sort(([a], [b]) => a - b)
  let i = array.length - 1
  while (i) {
    if (array[i][1] > array[--i][1]) {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
}

console.log(solution("bbbaacdafe"))
console.log(solution("aaaabbbc"))
console.log(solution("aabbb"))
console.log(solution("aaabbb"))
console.log(solution("aabbbcccccc"))
console.log(solution("bbc"))
```